# Is there a code to number equation that is output as (2.1)*?

Tags: numbering

If we have a code like this:

```
\begin{align}\label{eq:d2}

&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)Z\}^{\top}\ =\ R(X,\ Y)Z\ -\ A_{h(Y,\ Z)}X\ +\ A_{h(X,\ Z)}Y,\\

&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)Z\}^{\bot}\ =\ (\nabla_{X}h)(Y,\ Z)\ -\ (\nabla_{Y}h)(X,\ Z),\\

&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)V\}^{\top}\ =\ (\nabla_{Y}A)_{V}X\ -\ (\nabla_{X}A)_{V}Y,\\

&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)V\}^{\bot}\ =\ R^{\bot}(X, Y)V\ +\ h(Y,\ A_{V}X)\ -\ h(X,\ A_{V}Y),
\end{align}
```

then in the output the equations are numbered like this:

...(2.1),

...(2.2),

...(2.3),

...(2.4).

Is there a way to write a code so that the numbers in the output of dual equations look like this:

...(2.1)*,

...(2.2)*,

...(2.3)*,

...(2.4)*.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are okay with the star being inside the brackets, i.e. `(2.1*)`you can use `\tag{2.1*}` and the `\eqref` would also be in that style. But think of the point, that your numbering is manual in this case, i.e. if you add an numbered equation before `(2.1*)` your numbering is not ordered anymore. So could you be precise, whether you wand that, too? Which packages/documentclass are you using? An MWE would be helpful :)

Comment: I need exactly (2.1)* and so on. I use a class \documentclass[seceq]{iis}
 which is special for one journal.

Comment: Do all equation number expressions have to be terminated by an asterisk, or just a few selected ones?

Comment: Why all those spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state this explicitly in the posting, but I assume that *all* equations need to be "numbered" with an asterisk. I further assume you'll need to cross-reference some of these specially marked equations and that the asterisks should show up in the cross-references as well. One way to achieve the cross-referencing objective would be to use the `cleveref` package and its highly customizable `\cref` macro. In the code below, care is taken to make sure that the equation number, including the asterisk, is set in the upright font shape even if the surrounding material is set in italics. (It's conventional *not* to italicize equation numbers and their surrouding parentheses.)

I see from your code that you like to see a bit more whitespace around the symbols `=`, `-`, and `+` and that you insert spaces by hand around each and every one of these symbols to achieve this look. I believe it's far easier to simply change the length parameters `\thickmuskip` and `\medmuskip`, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment and '\numberwithin' macro
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%% formatting of equation "numbers"
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)*}}
\makeatother

%% formatting of cross-references to equations
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{equation~{\upshape (#2#1#3)*}}

\newcommand{\Rbar}{\overline{R}}  % shortcut macro

%% change the length parameters \thickmuskip and \medmuskip
\setlength\thickmuskip{10mu}  % default value -- 5mu
\setlength\medmuskip{8mu}     % default value -- 4mu

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}  % just for this example

\begin{align}
&\{\Rbar(X,Y)Z\}^{\top}=R(X,Y)Z-A_{h(Y,Z)}X+A_{h(X,Z)}Y\\
&\{\Rbar(X,Y)Z\}^{\bot}=(\nabla_{X}h)(Y,Z)-(\nabla_{Y}h)(X,Z) \label{eq:thisone}\\
&\{\Rbar(X,Y)V\}^{\top}=(\nabla_{Y}A)_{V}X-(\nabla_{X}A)_{V}Y\\
&\{\Rbar(X,Y)V\}^{\bot}=R^{\bot}(X,Y)V+h(Y,A_{V}X)-h(X,A_{V}Y)
\end{align}

\emph{A cross-reference to \cref{eq:thisone} in a sentence that's set in italics.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment.

It is not clear whether you want all equation numbers with a `*` or only some of them. This should be a rough hack you may find useful

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)*}}
\makeatother
  \begin{align}\label{eq:d2}
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)Z\}^{\top}\ =\ R(X,\ Y)Z\ -\ A_{h(Y,\ Z)}X\ +\ A_{h(X,\ Z)}Y,\\
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)Z\}^{\bot}\ =\ (\nabla_{X}h)(Y,\ Z)\ -\ (\nabla_{Y}h)(X,\ Z),\label{eq:d3}\\
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)V\}^{\top}\ =\ (\nabla_{Y}A)_{V}X\ -\ (\nabla_{X}A)_{V}Y,\\
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)V\}^{\bot}\ =\ R^{\bot}(X, Y)V\ +\ h(Y,\ A_{V}X)\ -\ h(X,\ A_{V}Y),
\end{align}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip)}}
\makeatother
  \begin{align}\label{eq:dd2}
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)Z\}^{\top}\ =\ R(X,\ Y)Z\ -\ A_{h(Y,\ Z)}X\ +\ A_{h(X,\ Z)}Y,\\
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)Z\}^{\bot}\ =\ (\nabla_{X}h)(Y,\ Z)\ -\ (\nabla_{Y}h)(X,\ Z),\label{eq:dd3}\\
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)V\}^{\top}\ =\ (\nabla_{Y}A)_{V}X\ -\ (\nabla_{X}A)_{V}Y,\\
&\{\overline{R}(X,\ Y)V\}^{\bot}\ =\ R^{\bot}(X, Y)V\ +\ h(Y,\ A_{V}X)\ -\ h(X,\ A_{V}Y),
\end{align}
From~\eqref{eq:d3} we get nothing similar to~\eqref{eq:dd3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you want to divide the four equations into two pairs, each of which has an equation and its dual, based on the presence of `\top` and `\bot`.

You can use the `\tag*` feature that allows pretty much everything as the “equation number”:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\zeroast}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Something}

We can refer to~\eqref{eq:d2} and to its dual \eqref{eq:d2}*:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:d2}
\{\overline{R}(X, Y)Z\}^{\top} &= R(X, Y)Z - A_{h(Y, Z)}X + A_{h(X, Z)}Y,\\
\tag*{\eqref{eq:d2}\zeroast}
\{\overline{R}(X, Y)Z\}^{\bot} &= (\nabla_{X}h)(Y, Z) - (\nabla_{Y}h)(X, Z),\\
\label{eq:d3}
\{\overline{R}(X, Y)V\}^{\top} &= (\nabla_{Y}A)_{V}X - (\nabla_{X}A)_{V}Y,\\
\tag*{\eqref{eq:d3}\zeroast}
\{\overline{R}(X, Y)V\}^{\bot} &= R^{\bot}(X, Y)V + h(Y, A_{V}X) - h(X, A_{V}Y),
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The `\zeroast` macro is just for the tag, so that the asterisk will occupy zero space and so be typeset past the right margin.

[image]

Don't use explicit spacing in math equations; the built-in rules take care of the spaces.

Comment: If `\eqref{eq:d2}*` occurs in italics mode -- say, in the body of some theorem that typesets its text material in italics -- the asterisk in "(1.1)*" will be set in italic rather than in upright mode. One way to fix that would be to write `\eqref{eq:d2}\textnormal{*}`.

Comment: @Mico Yes, of course